# How to define specific population for Public Opinion

Tags: mathematical-statistics, finite-population

I am trying to study the public opinion concept linked to quantitative measurement of opinion distributions and i am trying to define major parameters and methods that can help me starting from a certain finite number of people replying to a survey to generalize the results of that survey to say that this result can be considered as a public opinion.
Is there any statistical methods and parameters linked to country that i should integrate to define the concept of a public opinion ? what minimum number of people that must reply to a survey ? is there any intrinsic parameters linked to the survey it self ?

Comment: Do you understand the concepts of standard-error, confidence interval, statistical population, sample, parameter vs. statistic?  I'd look all those up on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

The population is the sampling frame. If you're using some non-random sampling scheme like convenience sampling, the population is harder to define.

Random samples of the same size from populations of different sizes have different margins of error; samples from smaller populations have smaller margins of error. Statistical methods often assume infinite population sizes. Read about "finite population correction" to see how to adjust for the population size.

When you have a large, heterogeneous population, you'll need to be concerned as to whether everyone will interpret the questionnaire the way you expect them to, so you might want to put more time into questionnaire development and pilot testing.